# decimal expansion and square roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

given a decimal expansion

$$ 0.345345345... $$

then we can recover the fraction from this decimal expansion , in this case $ \frac{345}{999} $

my question is if for a non-periodic decimal expansion

$$ 0.451235132535126535126164616146462462 $$ we can find two numbers a and b integers so

$$ a+ \sqrt{b} = 0.451235132535126535126164616146462462 $$ or if there is a theroem which make it an impssible task.

Comment: Such a representation is not guaranteed to exist (take $\pi$, for example, or even $\sqrt{2} \over 2$).

Comment: um of course but assume it exists and it converges to a number of the form $ a+ \sqrt{b} $ with a and b integers, could we get a and b from its decimal expansions ?

Comment: How do you describe a non-periodic decimal expansion completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you suspect your number is of this form, you can look at its continued fraction.  Anything of the form $a + \sqrt{b}$ with $a$ and $b$ rational will have an eventually  periodic continued fraction, and you can recover $a$ and $b$ from that.  For example, your $0.451235132535126535126164616146462462$ has continued fraction
$$[0; 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9, 6, 1, 262, 4, 2, 13, 2, 4, 1, 1, 37, 1, 1, 88, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8, 1, 4, 1, 1 \ldots]$$
i.e.
$$ 0 + 1/(2 + 1/(4 + 1/(1 + 1/\ldots $$

and this gives no sign of becoming periodic.

Comment: that was the idea.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can't do this for [transcendental numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_numbers). If we could do this for a transcendental number $\alpha$, then $\alpha$ would be a root of a polynomial of the form $$x^2-2ax+a^2-b,$$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of decimal places after $46462462\ldots$ in your question.  If you only want a finite number of decimal places to match, then yes, it is always possible to find integers $a,b$ such that $a + \sqrt{b}$ agrees with some fixed irrational number to any given precision (the higher the precision, the larger $a$ and $b$ might have to be).  The reason that's true is that the sequence $\{\sqrt{n}\}$ increases to infinity but slowly, in the sense that $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \to 0$.   Any sequence with these two properties will have its fractional parts dense in $[0,1)$.

On the other hand, if you want the two sides to be *exactly* equal, then this is usually not possible, because there are only countably many pairs of integers and uncountably many real numbers.  A very nice feature of quadratic irrationals is that they may be identified by a [periodic continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction), much like a rational number can be identified by a periodic decimal expansion.

In this sense you can compute continued fraction coefficients to convince yourself that a given sequence of digits has the form $a + \sqrt{b}$, with the caveat that one can only compute finitely many digits, and any finite number of digits might appear to match $a + \sqrt{b}$ (see the first paragraph) only to disagree in the next digit.